# TypeError: ...[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong at this part of script:

```
        function refreshLabels() {

            // loop through all document elements
            var allnodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

            for (var i=0, max=allnodes.length; i < max; i++) {
                // get id current elements
                var idname = allnodes[i].id;
                // if id exists, set get id current elements
                if (idname !== '') {
                    allnodes[i].textContent = multilang.get(idname);
                }
            }
        }
```

Firebug always say:
"TypeError: allnodes[i] is undefined"

I can't find any solution to fix this - is this part wrong?

```
"for (var i=0, max=allnodes.length; i < max; i++)"
```

Btw., also Chrome say it - so its not just a FF problem.

Comment: I have tested the code by replacing `allnodes[i].textContent = multilang.get(idname);` with `console.log(allnodes[i].textContent)`. I have not recieved any errors... Could you tell us more about the error message? What line does it point to in your code?

Comment: I can't read a full description of `textContent` fast enough, but is it certain that assigning to it will not destroy child elements? You are caching the length at the start, so if it would, it's an easy explanation.

Comment: @Ivan - That is strange - can this be a problem of loading? Maybe the page isnt rdy and the script fires or something like this?

Comment: I think @ASDFGerte is right: `Setting this property on a node removes all of its children and replaces them with a single text node with the given value.` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Description)

Comment: Ok, thx for the tip! Damn ;( ...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with changing the textContent is that you are actually mutating the node child's nodes of the `allnodes` array and thereby also mutating  the length of the `allnodes` array, reducing its size so that the loop continues running past the end of the newly shortened array.

Refer to MDN web docs for what [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Description) is doing:

```js
function refreshLabels() {

  // loop through all document elements
  var allnodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
  console.log(allnodes.length)

  for (var i = 0, max = allnodes.length; i < max; i++) {
    // get id current elements
    var idname = allnodes[i].id;
    // if id exists, set get id current elements
    if (idname !== '') {
      allnodes[i].textContent = idname;
      console.log(allnodes.length)      // this length will change
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @user10047187, I think you should post another question on how you can solve this problem, you seem to be wanting to translate your page.